# Exception in thread "main" chisel3.package$ChiselException: Unable to locate the elaborated circuit, did chisel3.stage.phases.Elaborate run correctly

Tags: chisel, chiseltest, firrtl

While setting up the Chisel in my linux environment and running a small and_gate test .

I am getting error like this:

```
[error] Exception in thread "main" chisel3.package$ChiselException: Unable to locate the elaborated circuit, did chisel3.stage.phases.Elaborate run correctly
[error]     at chisel3.stage.phases.AddSerializationAnnotations.$anonfun$transform$1(AddSerializationAnnotations.scala:25)
[error]     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
[error]     at chisel3.stage.phases.AddSerializationAnnotations.transform(AddSerializationAnnotations.scala:25)
[error]     at chisel3.stage.phases.AddSerializationAnnotations.transform(AddSerializationAnnotations.scala:15)
[error]     at firrtl.options.DependencyManager.$anonfun$transform$5(DependencyManager.scala:280)
[error]     at firrtl.Utils$.time(Utils.scala:53)
[error]     at firrtl.options.DependencyManager.$anonfun$transform$3(DependencyManager.scala:280)
[error]     at scala.collection.LinearSeqOps.foldLeft(LinearSeq.scala:183)
[error]     at scala.collection.LinearSeqOps.foldLeft$(LinearSeq.scala:179)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:79)
[error]     at firrtl.options.DependencyManager.transform(DependencyManager.scala:269)
[error]     at firrtl.options.DependencyManager.transform$(DependencyManager.scala:255)
[error]     at firrtl.options.PhaseManager.transform(DependencyManager.scala:443)
[error]     at circt.stage.ChiselStage.run(ChiselStage.scala:67)
[error]     at firrtl.options.Stage$$anon$1.transform(Stage.scala:42)
[error]     at firrtl.options.Stage$$anon$1.transform(Stage.scala:42)
[error]     at firrtl.options.Stage.$anonfun$transform$3(Stage.scala:45)
[error]     at scala.collection.LinearSeqOps.foldLeft(LinearSeq.scala:183)
[error]     at scala.collection.LinearSeqOps.foldLeft$(LinearSeq.scala:179)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:79)
[error]     at firrtl.options.Stage.$anonfun$transform$2(Stage.scala:45)
[error]     at logger.Logger$.$anonfun$makeScope$2(Logger.scala:137)
[error]     at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:59)
[error]     at logger.Logger$.makeScope(Logger.scala:135)
[error]     at firrtl.options.Stage.transform(Stage.scala:45)
[error]     at firrtl.options.Stage.execute(Stage.scala:56)
[error]     at firrtl.options.StageMain.main(Stage.scala:69)
[error]     at circt.stage.ChiselMain.main(ChiselStage.scala)
[error] Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
[error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed 06-Mar-2023, 3:02:31 pm
```

It is saying like firrtl tool was not there and the design was not elaborated. Can anyone who had setup the chisel environment in their local machine. Can you help me with this..?

It tried by cloning the firrtl from github, but not worked.

Comment: Please can you give the source code ?

Comment: It got worked after adding the library dependencies correctly. Thank you for replying back @FabienM

Comment: If you solve it, please add the solution in answer (and add the code in question too)

Comment: Previously , I didn't added the code to get the Verilog correctly. Then i modified it to   `object FullAdd extends App{
 emitVerilog (new FullAdder(16), Array("--target-dir","generated/FullAdder"))
}
` . then it worked fine.